# Python Pool EOFError:

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle, pool

I am using python pool to multiprocess a function in which a panda data frame is read and store using 'pd.pickle'.  when number of item in my list to be processed get more than 10 I got the following error:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.pyc in get(self, timeout)
552             return self._value
553         else:
--> 554             raise self._value
555 
556     def _set(self, i, obj):

EOFError:
```

here some more information maybe useful:

in my_function():

```
df = pd.read_pickle('df.pkl')
 . 
 .
 .
 .
df.to_pickle('df.pkl')
```

for multi processing:

```
  pool = Pool(processes=30)
  pool.map(my_function, lst[1:10])
  pool.close() 
  pool.join()
```

if I use

```
lst[1:40]
```

then I got the mentioned error. could any one help with the reason behind?

Comment: How does `my_function()` relate to the rest of the code? Is that actually `create_data_frame`?

Comment: Is every subprocess reading and writing the same `df.pkl` file?

Comment: @TomDalton yes by create_data_frame I meant my_function() . and for the second question also yes. indeed I should update df.pkl in each subprocess.

Comment: So you're reading and writing the exact same pickle file (`df.pkl`) in every subprocess?

Comment: @TomDalton yes and I think pool can not handle this when number of items are increased.

Comment: You're using the same file 10 times in parallel? It's not surprising that this isn't working, since you potentially have some subprocesses reading from the file when other subprocesses have just stated writing to it (and therefore it's empty or incomplete). It's unclear exactly what your intention is here but this is definitely the problem.